# Highcharts - After setting minTickInterval to one day, tickmarks aren't appearing under points

Tags: javascript, graph, highcharts

I am creating a Highcharts table rendering a value per day over the last few days. I only want one tickmark per day and am using `minTickInterval: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000`. However, each day's tickmark isn't appearing directly under the point in the graph for that day. The tickmarks are appearing far to the left of its corresponding day's point.

An example of what I am seeing can be viewed here (this is not my graph, but an example that I found while searching for a solution; it is experiencing the same problem I am) - http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/bv9ED/

Thank you for any help that you can provide!

Comment: The ticks will be placed at midnight of the given date, eg: `2017-01-05 00:00:00` for the January 5th date; your data points have specific times , and they will be plotted according to those times, so the points and ticks will only line up if your points have a time of midnight as well.

Comment: Thank you, this comment helped me find my root issue! My data was set for midnight of my local timezone, but Highcharts was plotting the data with respect to UTC timezone. Because of this, each point was offset by the number of hours between my local timezone vs UTC. Setting the global option, `setUTC` to false allowed Highcharts to also use my local timezone (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/global.useUTC).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use axis [tickPositioner](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickPositioner)/[tickPositions](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickPositions) to specify the exact positions for the ticks.

For the example you provided, you can grab the series xData and set them as the ticks - the ticks will be in the same place as the points.

```
tickPositioner: function () {
          var tickPositions = this.chart.series[0].xData.slice();
          tickPositions.info = this.tickPositions.info;

          return tickPositions;
        }
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/bv9ED/29/

Comment: This worked perfectly to center each tick under its point.
In my original question, I said that I was only using a few points. However, I sometimes may need to use a large number of points. Using `tickPositioner` seems to force a tick under each and every point - ticks start getting squished after there are more than ~15 on my screen. How can I keep the ticks centered over their points, but still allow highcharts to limit the number of ticks when there is a large number of points?

Comment: @NickPierson You should filter the tick positions array then. See example http://jsfiddle.net/bv9ED/30/

Comment: Thank you for the follow-up and suggestions! I actually was able to find the root cause of the offset (related to jlbriggs comment above) which removed the need for using `tickPositioner` - my data was set for midnight of my local timezone, but Highcharts was plotting the data with respect to UTC timezone. Because of this, each point was offset by the number of hours between my local timezone vs UTC. Setting the global option, `setUTC` to false allowed Highcharts to also use my local timezone (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/global.useUTC). Thank you for all your help!